# Strings in Java

Tags: java

I have a code:

```
for(int i=0;i<fList.size();i++){
    String targets="";
    String values="";
    String sql="INSERT INTO "+tableName+"("+targets+") VALUES("+values+")";
    Map<Column, String> attrs=fList.get(i).getAttributes();
    for(int j=0;j<columns.size();j++){
        if(columns.get(j).getName().equalsIgnoreCase("kadnum")){
            targets=targets+"kadnum,";
            System.out.println("targets:"+targets);
            values=values+attrs.get(columns.get(j))+",";
            System.out.println("values:"+values);
        }
        if(columns.get(j).getName().equalsIgnoreCase("support_num")){
            targets=targets+"support_num";
            values=values+attrs.get(columns.get(j))+",";
        }
    }
    System.out.println("sql="+sql);
}
```

And get out put:

```
INSERT INTO parcels () VALUES()
```

But if u change `System.out.println("sql="+sql);` to    `System.out.println("targets="+targets);` i get : `targets=kadnum,`
 Why string sql not change?

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Never do this. Use a framework to connect to your db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating the `sql` string before adding anything to the `targets` string. So at the time `sql` string is created, the `targets` string is still empty. Create the `sql` string later at the end to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Move the declaration of sql to end just before `println`.

```
 String sql="INSERT INTO "+tableName+"("+targets+") VALUES("+values+")";
 System.out.println("sql="+sql);
```

Comment: So i gonna constract `sql` only when i want to use it?

Comment: Yes. Additionally, usage of `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` in case of multi-threaded applications is recommended when concatentating Strings in Java.

Comment: @KliverMax, You need to construct `sql` only when you have other variables `targets` and `values` ready or shall I say initialized with required values.

Answer (score 0):

```
String sql="INSERT INTO "+tableName+"("+targets+") VALUES("+values+")";
```

should come just above

```
System.out.println("sql="+sql);
```